# Can't find mysqladmin on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I am trying to set admin path on Netbeans and I'm unable to find mysqladmin on OSX 10.6.8 after installing the MySQL Community Server.  Anybody have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac, by default, mysql is installed to `/usr/local/mysql/`

The path to the binaries (mysql, mysqladmin, etc.) should therefore be `/usr/local/mysql/bin`

Comment: One additional bit of info...  Mac users will need to type in the path... or the start of it (like '/usr') BEFORE you can use the Browse button for the field in the 'MySQL Server Properties' dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Mac's default location of MySQL instance: `/usr/local/mysql`

Path to `mysqladmin`: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin`